# How to Modify Values of Cell Directly Right of Current Cell

Tags: vba

I have this code:

```
Sub yeartest()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("I7:I17")
If cell.Value = "8" Then
cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen

End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

which modifies all cells =8 in the range to turn green in color.

What I would like for this to do would be the same principle except if a cell in the range is =8 then the cell directly right of it turns green. Say for example the cell I9 was =8, then the cell directly right of it, J9, turns green.

To do this I need to implement `=RC[+1]` in some way.

I tried:

```
RC[+1].Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Offset()

```
Cell.Offset(,1).Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen
```

Answer (score 0):

this will color both cells with one command, if you want

Cell.Resize(1,2).Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen